# "Method or Data Member Not Found" When Trying to Execute Database Code

Tags: vb6, ado

I have a test project I'm using to familiarise myself with VB6. Just a listbox, a button to get info, and a button to clear info:

[image: VB6 Form]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnGet_Click()
    lstResults.DataSource = GetMenuItems
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click()
    lstResults.Clear
End Sub

Public Function GetMenuItems() As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "File Name=C:\connString.udl"

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetMenuItems"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute()
    GetMenuItems = rs
End Function
```

The following error appears when I click the Get Items button (btnGet):

> Compile Error: Method or Data Member Not Found

At first I thought it might be something to do with the event/button, that some sort of binding between them wasn't present. But just putting in something like "MsgBox("Hello")" works fine. Yet it doesn't even seems to get to the line where the GetMenuItems function is called before throwing the error.
This being my first whirl with VB, I'm a little stumped.

EDIT - I've had a look at the UDL file I was using too. Tested that and its connecting ok on its own.

Comment: I would have thought `Set GetMenuItems = rs`

Comment: Gave that a go, but no joy. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: As an aside, avoid `Dim ... As New ...` in VB6. It's legal syntax, but doesn't do what you'd expect, and what it does do isn't intuitive. Much safer to `Dim ... As ...` and `Set ... = New ...`. More details happily supplied if you want 'em :)

Comment: I didn't know that at all. From what I've read just now, it seems that if you use that syntax, a new instance will be created each time you make reference to the object. Or am I misunderstanding? Cheers anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Sub btnGet_Click`, use

```
Set lstResults.DataSource = GetMenuItems
```

Assigning object references without using `Set` is hardly ever the right thing to do. For what it's worth, omitting `Set` references the left-hand side's default property; this was part of VB6 (OK, VB4, when classes were introduced) as a help to VB3 programmers, before there were such things as objects. Whatever kind of object `lstResults.DataSource` returns likely does not have a default property, leading to the "Method or data member not found" error.

Comment: That took care of it alright. Now, on to the myriad other mistakes in my tiny test project :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

- You've got a private sub btnGet_Click() calling a public function GetMenuItems(), which may cause problems.
- Also I'm not sure you can use a udl as the connection string.  Instead, open the UDL (you may need to change the file extension to .txt temporarily), take the connection string out, and use that in place of the file name.
- Also, check the stored procedure exists dbo.GetMenuItems